# Closed the Matching End Tag on Visualforce page but still getting error

Tags: visualforce, salesforcedx

Even i have close the Matching tag in the below VF page still getting error as i have not closed the Matching end tag.

```
<apex:page standardController="Statement__c" extensions="Payments_Extension" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Quick Payment" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value = "Save Payment" action = "{!savePayment}" disabled="{!success}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageMessages/>

        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

            <apex:selectList label="Payment Method" value="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId}">
                <apex:selectOption value="{!paymentRecordTypes}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="paymentMethodDetails"/>
            </apex:selectList>

            <apex:inputfield value = "{!thisPayment.Amount__c}"/>
            <apex:inputfield value = "{!thisPayment.Billing_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:inputfield value = "{!thisPayment.Billing_Street__c}"/>
            <apex:inputfield value = "{!thisPayment.Billing_City__c}"/>
            <apex:inputfield value = "{!thisPayment.Billing_State__c}"/>
            <apex:inputfield value = "{!thisPayment.Billing_Postal_Code__c}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:outputPanel id="paymentMethodDetails">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId!=null && recordTypeMap[thisPayment.recordTypeId] == 'Check}">

                <apex:inputfield value = "{!thisPayment.Check_Account_Number__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value = "{!thisPayment.Check_Routing_Number__c}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId!=null 
                                                         && recordTypeMap[thisPayment.recordTypeId] == 'Credit Card">
                <apex:inputField value="{!thisPayment.Credit_Card_Number__c}"/>

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputField value = "Credit Card Expiration"/>
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                        <apex:inputField value ="{!thisPayment.Credit_Card_Expiration_month__c}"/>
                        <apex:inputField value ="{!thisPayment.Expiration_Year__c}"/>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!thisPayment.Expiration_Year__c}">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!expirationYears}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:inputSecret value="{!thisPayement.Credit_Card_Security_Code__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Line no 49 Error :

The element type "apex:outputpanel" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apex page end tag is missing at the end. Add the below code at the end of the file.

```
</apex:page>
```

Also `'}` is missing from your rendered condition at the below line.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId!=null 
                                                         && recordTypeMap[thisPayment.recordTypeId] == 'Credit Card">
```

which should be

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId!=null 
                                                         && recordTypeMap[thisPayment.recordTypeId] == 'Credit Card'}">
```

Comment: It is closed but still i am getting the error

Comment: sorry for update i forget to add the last code.

Comment: No worries, your new problem is solved by Vijay's answer

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because you have not closed the `rendered` attribute of one of the `<apex:pageBlockSection>`

Replace this below code

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId!=null 
                                                         && recordTypeMap[thisPayment.recordTypeId] == 'Credit Card">
```

with

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!thisPayment.recordTypeId!=null 
                                                         && recordTypeMap[thisPayment.recordTypeId] == 'Credit Card'}">
```

Salesforce does not show you the exact issues with the visualforce code when you don't close the tags properly.